# column selection from string variables using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to select columns from string variables, and preform some calculations.

Let's assume I am analyzing `iris` and I want to find all the ratios between lengths and widths.

```
# Manual mutation (ie: adding the column names explicitly in the mutate statement) 
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.ratio = Sepal.Length/Sepal.Width, 
         Petal.ratio = Petal.Length/Petal.Width)

# Output: 
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.ratio Petal.ratio
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    1.457143        7.00
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    1.633333        7.00
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    1.468750        6.50
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    1.483871        7.50
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    1.388889        7.00
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    1.384615        4.25
```

**Question:** 
Is there any way to use a variable or a dataframe (like the `ratioSets` defined below) that specifies the column names?

```
# Predefined or preprocessed column name set: 
ratioSets = rbind(c(value = 'Sepal.ratio', numerator = 'Sepal.Length', denominator = 'Sepal.Width'), 
                 c(value = 'Petal.ratio', numerator = 'Petal.Length', denominator = 'Petal.Width'))

# Automated mutation:
iris %>% 
  mutate(
    # How can I use the ratioSets here?
    # Something like : ratioSets$value = ratioSets$numerator / ratioSets$denominator
  )


# Expected Output: 
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.ratio Petal.ratio
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    1.457143        7.00
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    1.633333        7.00
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    1.468750        6.50
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    1.483871        7.50
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    1.388889        7.00
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    1.384615        4.25
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you include a couple of lines of your intended output?

Comment: @Maiasaura I added some further explanation to the question. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense now. This is a bit challenging in `dplyr` but I am thinking through it.

Answer (score 1):

One way which assumes that numerator is always before denominator(i.e. length before width)

```
sapply(unique(sub('\\..*', '', names(iris[,-ncol(iris)]))), function(i)
        Reduce('/', iris[,-ncol(iris)][,grepl(i, sub('\\..*', '', names(iris[,-ncol(iris)])))]))
```

or

```
head(cbind(iris, sapply(unique(sub('\\..*', '', names(iris[,-ncol(iris)]))), 
         function(i) Reduce('/', iris[,-ncol(iris)][,grepl(i, sub('\\..*', '', names(iris[,-ncol(iris)])))]))))

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    Sepal Petal
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 1.457143  7.00
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 1.633333  7.00
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 1.468750  6.50
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 1.483871  7.50
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 1.388889  7.00
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 1.384615  4.25
```

Comment: Thank you @Sotos . Do you know if there is a way to put that through the `dplyr`'s  `mutate`?

Comment: I m sure there is. It would be a good exercise to translate my code into `dplyr` :)

Comment: Actually, the main challenge I am facing is passing variable colname through dplyr. So if in the example, I've preset some values that I couldn't correctly index through dplyr.